# I am learning JavaScript and cannot understand the code below

Tags: javascript, arrays, navbar

```
 const navtabs = document.querySelectorAll('a')
    const ul = document.querySelector('ul')
    for( let i = 0; i < navtabs.length;i++){
      navtabs[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        ul.classList.add('clicked')
      })
    }
```

Can anyone please explain me this code? It's working but I don't know how. Actually it was used to collapse navbar after it's clicked in mobile view.

Answer (score 1):

#### `const navtabs = document.querySelectorAll('a')`

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

`document.querySelectorAll('a')` selects all the `<a>` elements in the HTML document and returns an array of objects with all the HTML elements. Hence, `navtabs` will have an array of objects that references `<a>` elements.

#### `const ul = document.querySelector('ul')`

[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

`document.querySelector('ul')` selects the first `<ul>` element in the HTML document and returns only the first `ul` element from the HTML document.

Now, since `navtabs` is an array, we loop through all the `<a>` elements in a for loop and add a 'click' event listener to each of the a element using `addEventListener`.
That means for every click on the a elements, we call the provided callback function which is:

```
function(){
    ul.classList.add('clicked')
}
```

When the above callback function is executed, we add a class name 'clicked' to the `ul` element.

Try this out:

```js
 const navtabs = document.querySelectorAll('a')
    const ul = document.querySelector('ul')
    for( let i = 0; i < navtabs.length;i++){
      navtabs[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        ul.classList.add('clicked')
      })
    }
```

```css
.clicked {
  background: red;
}
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Cart</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>About</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```